# My loop is not always hitting the last couple of array items, and occasionally fails one of my conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

This is a little program I am making to generate my friends' secret santa names. When I have everyone's emails, I will create an array, and in the loop send an email to the current person (from my email) with the message.

Currently I have it writing out to an HTML page to get the results. Occasionally it does not go through all steps of the loop (will skip the last couple of people) and sometimes it breaks one of my if statements, and allows a match I didn't want.

This is a simple program and I didn't want to overthink it, but apparently my first shot it at isn't working. Can anyone suggest a more reliable way to make this? I was considering a while loop, that evaluates to false if it returns an unwanted match.

```js
var names = [
  "Jessica",
  "William",
  "Justine",
  "Max",
  "Funke",
  "Zach",
  "Emery",
  "Autumn",
  "Ethan",
  "Rhnea",
  "Richard",
  "Laura Bane",
  "Toran",
  "Carla",
  "Matt",
  "Joe",
  "Andy",
  "Evan",
  "Pat"
];

var names2 = [
  "Jessica",
  "William",
  "Justine",
  "Max",
  "Funke",
  "Zach",
  "Emery",
  "Autumn",
  "Ethan",
  "Rhnea",
  "Richard",
  "Laura Bane",
  "Toran",
  "Carla",
  "Matt",
  "Joe",
  "Andy",
  "Evan",
  "Pat"
];

var emails = [];
var message = "";

var generateMatch = function() {
  var match = Math.floor(Math.random() * names2.length);

  if (names[i] != names2[match]) {
    if (names2[match] == undefined) {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Jessica" && names2[match] == "William") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Jessica" && names2[match] == "Evan") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "William" && names2[match] == "Jessica") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "William" && names2[match] == "Evan") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Justine" && names2[match] == "Max") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Max" && names2[match] == "Justine") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Funke" && names2[match] == "Zach") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Zach" && names2[match] == "Funke") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Emery" && names2[match] == "Autumn") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Autumn" && names2[match] == "Justine") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Ethan" && names2[match] == "Rhnea") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Rhnea" && names2[match] == "Ethan") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Richard" && names2[match] == "Laura Bane") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Laura Bane" && names2[match] == "Richard") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Toran" && names2[match] == "Carla") {
      generateMatch();
    }
    if (names[i] == "Carla" && names2[match] == "Toran") {
      generateMatch();
    } else {
      message = "Hello " + names[i] + ", your match is " + names2[match] + "<br>";
      names2.splice(match, 1);


    }
  } else {
    generateMatch();
  }
}

var length = names.length + 1;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  generateMatch();
  document.write(message);
  //window.open('mailto:' + email[i] + '?subject=Brozmas&body=' + message);
}
```

Comment: Are those supposed to be exceptions? As in, don't match these two people together?

Comment: Looks like a stack overflow happens and the execution stops.. pun intended.

Comment: Recursion is probably not a good idea for a case like this, you'd be best served with a `for` or `while` loop. It'd be much easier to debug.

Comment: You have an odd number of people...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably not an optimal use for recursion. From my cursory reading of your code, you want to randomize matching between two names with a number of built-in exceptions. You could do something like this with a `while` loop.

```
while (names.length > 0)
    pick names from names and names2
    if the pair of names is a built-in exception:
        continue
    output the matching name pair
    pop the names from names and names2
```

This loop will run as long as there is a person in the `names` array. This guarantees that everyone in the `names` array will have a Secret Santa match. `continue` means that the loop will skip execution if the name pair is one of your built-in exceptions and popping the names from the arrays shows that there's a match.

P.S. You might be better served by using a more descriptive name for the arrays like `from` and `to`.

Comment: You might enter an infinite loop in case some of the last cases can only be exceptions

Comment: Yeah, that's a risk you run into when you're dealing with looping and pre-described exceptions. It's possible to avoid this problem if you add some break clauses if the `names2` or `to` array only contains exception cases.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I re-read your original post and I see the issue now. With the no-match rules you've selected, it isn't possible to generate enough proper matches for it to succeed and generates an infinite loop. If I add a "tries" flag to stop it from looping forever and checking how many times we've tried to find a match, we're left every time with roughly 50% of the names unmatched, because of the rules. Anyone else want to chime in?

I cleaned up your code a bit while still using recursion. This generates a from-to array that you could expand upon to generate emails to all the paired individuals.

```js
var names = [
   {name:"Jessica", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['William', 'Evan'], tries:0},
    {name:"William", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Jessica', 'Evan'], tries:0},
    {name:"Justine", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Max'], tries:0},
    {name:"Max", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Justine'], tries:0},
    {name:"Funke", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Zach'], tries:0},
    {name:"Zach", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Funke'], tries:0},
    {name:"Emery", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Autumn'], tries:0},
    {name:"Autumn", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Emery', 'Justine'], tries:0},
    {name:"Ethan", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Rhnea'], tries:0},
    {name:"Rhnea", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Ethan'], tries:0},
    {name:"Laura Bane", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Richard'], tries:0},
    {name: "Richard", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Laura Bane'], tries:0},
    {name:"Toran", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Calra'], tries:0},
    {name:"Carla", email: "", match: null, noMatch: ['Toran'], tries:0},
    {name:"Matt", email: "", match: null, noMatch: [], tries:0},
    {name:"Joe", email: "", match: null, noMatch: [], tries:0},
    {name:"Andy", email: "", match: null, noMatch: [], tries:0},
    {name:"Evan", email: "", match: null, noMatch: [], tries:0},
    {name:"Pat", email: "", match: null, noMatch: [], tries:0},
    {name: "No Match Found", email: "NoMatch@NoMatch.com", match: 99, noMatch: [], tries:0} 
];

let generatedEmails = [];

function assignMatch(arr, i) {
 if(arr.tries == 2) arr.match = names.length-1;
 if(arr.match === null || arr.tries < 2) {
  let randomIndex = (Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length));
   if(names[randomIndex].match != null || randomIndex === i || arr.noMatch.contains(names[randomIndex].name)){
     arr.tries++;
     assignMatch(arr, i);
    } else {
     arr.match = randomIndex;
      names[randomIndex].match = i;
    }
  }
}

Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i] == obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function generateEmails(arr, i) {
 if(arr.name != "No Match Found" || names[arr.match].name != "No Match Found"){ 
    let content = {
      fromName: arr.name,
      fromEmail: arr.email,
      toName: names[arr.match].name,
      toEmail: names[arr.match].email
    };
    generatedEmails.push(content);
   }
}


names.forEach((arr, i) => assignMatch(arr, i));
names.forEach((arr, i) => generateEmails(arr, i));

console.table(generatedEmails);
```

Hopefully this helps out a bit. Don't hesitate to ask questions.